# jQuery Ajax POST Request - Response Text empty ans status is 400 Bad Request in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I have the following jQuery AJAX request:

```
function addRecord() {    
    console.log('addRecord');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',        
        url: rootURL,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        data: formToJSON(),        
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('form submitted successfully');            
            alert('data'+data);
        },
        error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
            alert("Failed to process request correctly, please try again");

            console.log('xhRequest: ' + xhRequest + "\n");
            console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
            console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
        }
    });
}

function formToJSON() {
return JSON.stringify({"dateofVisit": $('#dateofVisit').val()}); 
}
```

Following is the output that i receive in firebug.

### Response Headers:

```
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Meth...    GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Head...    Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With
Content-Type    text/plain
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Thu, 24 Oct 2013 09:37:34 GMT
Connection  close
Request Headersview source
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer http://mydomain.com/DemoPurpose/demo.html
Content-Length  28
Origin  http://mydomain.com
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

### POST:

```
JSON    
dateofVisit
    "23-10-2013"
Source
{"dateofVisit":"23-10-2013"}
```

### Response:

```
empty
```

### Console output:

```
xhRequest: [object Object]
ErrorText: error
thrownError:
```

I am new to jquery, so basically dont know where i am doing the mistake. one thing is sure that its going to error part of ajax call but why? its able to form json...then why its going to error part? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

from [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
when you put `dataType=json`, it means you should not return the empty content.

"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

And also, you need check your response status is 200 not 400.

Your server side code has some problem.

```
@POST @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) 
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN}) @Path("/hello") 
//---------------------^^^ why you use plain text? why not application json
public Response create(String name) throws JSONException
{
 System.out.println("creating record for account");
 //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(name);
 //------------------------------^^^^^ it's not jsonformat, error should be here
 //try this way
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
 jsonObj.append("name",name);
 return Response.status(201).entity(jsonObj).build();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying. Sorry i forgot to add that i am getting the response status as 400 Bad Request with response as empty.

Comment: sorry, you didn't mention your server related code. But have you tried the suggestion above, to change the empty response to  `null` or `{}` instead?

Comment: I have this post method:@POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})  
    @Path("/hello")
    public Response create(String name) throws JSONException{
        System.out.println("creating record for account");            
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(name); return Response.status(201).entity(jsonObj).build();} I am getting the 500 Internal error and the response tab in firebug is blank. Please let me know what is the correct way to send the response for the post method.